# Multiple Custom Data-Binds on same DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

Searched but couldn't find the answer elsewhere...

I have a series of custom Knockout binding handlers, and am trying to run three different ones on one DOM element.

E.g.

```
data-bind="heightToContentSize:'scroll', toggletargethover:'pageWrapper', className:'removeArrows'"
```

Problem is, Knockout is only executing the first one, and ignoring the rest of them.  There are no errors in console.  I was under the impression that you could use an unlimited number of unique binding handlers on one DOM element, granted they are separated by a comma.

Can you chain custom databinds with a comma like I have above?  Is my logic in my statement above incorrect?

Comment: are the any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No errors in browser console, comes through perfectly.  I assume Knockout is ignoring the chained binding handlers and thus is not displaying error.

Comment: are all the bindings registered with knockout?

Comment: Yeah.  They will work if you bind them by themselves.  But when I start chaining them to the DOM element is when only the first one will fire.

Comment: i'm not sure why it wouldn't work at the moment.  When you register a binding handler, it gets added to the default binding handlers in knockout. so it really shouldn't be any different to having multiple default bindings (like text, css, click) on the element.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that will highlight the issue.

Comment: As @NathanFisher said, binding one or three should work as well. Are you sure there is no typo? Do you expect string parameters in your bindings? Also, you might want to check the `css binding`, maybe useful instead of your `className binding` (just a supposition as we don't have your code for the bindinghandlers)

Comment: Thanks Goto -- no typo as I've double checked.  I will throw together the fiddle shortly if I cant figure it out.

The className:removeArrows binding is actually just parameters for the toggletarget binding.  So technically it's just two bindings, but none the less no dice yet.

Answer (score 0):

Strange - but the problem was that Knockout was NOT ignoring white-space in the databind syntax.  I.e. if I did something like this....

```
data-bind="heightToContentSize:'something',click:referrerUrl"
```

Instead of something like this

```
data-bind="heightToContentSize:'something', click:referrerUrl"
```

(notice the whitespace after the comma)

Then it would work.  But Knockout is supposed to ignore all whitespaces I thought?
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
data-bind="heightToContentSize:scroll, toggletargethover:pageWrapper, className:removeArrows"
```

Or:

```
data-bind="heightToContentSize:scroll(), toggletargethover:pageWrapper(), className:removeArrows()"
```